# Autocompletion based on large sheet (2000+ rows)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

When using Google Spreadsheets, and you want to use Validation on a cell based on a range of values, you get a pretty nice *autocompletion* feature that makes data entry much nicer.

My most common application is in an inventory-like situation, where I reference inventory items through some kind of hash code or part number. My frequently used hashes are committed to my brain, but when i need a new part or I need a variation on an old one, I want a little help making sure I have the correct part# selected.

I always find that I want additional row context with my autocompletion, so now I think I want to make a sidebar addon that has smarter searching rules and also includes more contextual data to ensure that I have the part# I meant. Once I am sure of the part#, one button can push the selected result over to the currently active row.

This solution is a bit "heavier" than data validation, but it does exactly what I want.

Assuming that my inventory source is another spreadsheet, what is a good way to set up my Addon-Script Project?

I was thinking that my sidebar would call an HtmlService function that utilizes Cache Service to hold my "hash list" and a few bits of context in memory. I don't think I am looking at a heavy jQuery solution (only to build the autocomplete dialog as I type), but that is really the whole purpose of this question!

Any thoughts on high level project overview? I am fairly new to Apps Scripts in general, especially since the newer API's have been coming out since 2013.

Answer (score 2):

I did exactly that with my Budget Sheets, moved from Data Validation to Jquery's Autocomplete in a sidebar when the number of compositions jumped from 500 to 2.500, and it is a LOT faster, the search is faster than Autovalidation with 100 itens, the logic I use:

**Database:** 
It's base data is in a Spreadsheet, each time it is updated, there's an OnEdit function that will trigger in several minutes a DB update, this is so that the function won't run unecesserary on several times consectively for the same edit.
The DB is then stored in simple text in JSON format on Google Drive, it is a 2MB file generated from the Spreadsheet data, using `DriveApp.getFileById(id).setContet(JSON.stringify(myJsonDataFromSpreadsheet))`, the file generation and saving takes up to 30 seconds, the file reading is around 4segs.

**Sidebar:** 
Build a normal HTML - remember to use IFRAME option - and serve it, this is all in the docs, you'll have to send data from the HTML to GoogleScript (eg. the part# to insert) via google.script.run, and get back data (eg. the file with all the part numbers) with SuccessHandler in conjunction with google.script.run.

Main function references:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#custom_sidebars
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file -> First get the file With `DriveApp.getFileById(id)`.